# On Xamrin project getting project target framework not installed

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Code was running perfectly but suddenly showing

> The C# project is targeting MonoAndroid, version=v.90 which is not installed.

[image]

Using target framework:

```
 <TargetFrameworkVersion>v9.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AndroidApplication>True</AndroidApplication>
```

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2017

Comment: Please check have you reset the target framework? Please install the SDK in Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager), and note that you need keep online. For more about the VS 2017 support version, please refer to the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/9/9.0

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Visual studio 2019, it has much better support for Xamarin projects. In your Android SDK manager make sure you have Android 9.0 installed.